# UNION query problem

Tags: mysql

i have the following union query sql in my code

```
(SELECT TableA.ID, TableB.Group, '' as Name from TableA,TableB 
 where TableA.Ipfield=TableB.Androfield)
 UNION (SELECT TableA.ID,'',TableC.Name where TableA.irgroup=TableC.iqgroup)
```

The problem is I need to export this sql as csv file, while i export as csv it should show the column names at begiining of file so i had used '' as Name in query1 so as to display Name as one column along with ID and Group. But the issue here is the column names are displayed properly but the datas are displayed twice , one with Name as '' and another with value for Name.

Name is a field in TableC and not in tableA and tableB.
Is there any way i can display the datas only once with value for Name, I dont need the result with Name as '', it is just used to display the column name as Name along with ID and Group

Thanks Kindly Help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just union one row with column names firts:

```
select 'ID' as ID, 'Group' as Group, 'Name' as Name from dual
union
(and here goes the rest of your query)
```

Comment: Changing from UNION to UNION ALL would be quicker as it would not sort your results.

Comment: what is it about sorting here? @Kevin

Comment: UNION will not return duplicate rows between sets, it does this by sorting the results. see: http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2007/10/05/union-vs-union-all-performance/